# Charging lead acid batteries using DC-DC Buck Converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, lead-acid

Is there any disadvantage using an 18V 2A transformer with an adjustable DC-DC buck converter(link below) to charge a 12v 7Ah battery ?

I know that the charging current must not exceed C/10 (700mA here) and maximum voltage per cell shouldn't exceed 2.4V .

I guess the amount of current flowing into the battery should be proportional to the voltage difference between the charger and the battery. 
So i am planning to charge with a lower voltage initially like 13.6 V and gradually increase the to 14.1 V during the course of charging.

The Reasons for considering DC-DC buck converter is it's low cost and high efficiency. Lead acid battery chargers available here cost anywhere around 4 to 10 times  more than this setup.

Buck converter (3A max):
http://www.ebay.in/itm/LM2596-DC-DC-Buck-Converter-Step-Down-Power-Module-/201086952147?_trksid=p2054897.l5658

Comment: would the negative voters care to comment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spend a bit more and buy the version with a built-in current adjustment.

eg: http://www.aliexpress.com/item/High-Quality-5A-DC-to-DC-CC-CV-Lithium-Battery-Step-down-Charging-Board-Led-Power/32388356240.html (free shipping to most of the world - but not india)

http://www.ebay.in/itm/XL4015-5A-CC-CV-Lithium-Charger-DC-DC-Step-Down-Adjustable-Buck-Power-Module-/161879398799?hash=item25b0c3998f:g:JwYAAOSwhcJWOwOE (similar product on ebay india)

Answer (score 1):

The disadvantage is obvious: you have to babysit it or make a control circuit to do the adjustments for you... which is exactly what a dedicated charger [IC] does.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Any other disadvantage than the above mentioned one? . Also can you suggest a good charger IC ?

Comment: I am planning for a smart charger, so i don't have problem with controlling voltage programtically. http://hackaday.com/2015/08/19/microcontroller-adjustment-of-a-dc-to-dc-converter/

Comment: Spend a bit more and buy the version with a built-in current adjustment.

Comment: @Ryu_hayabusa: don't you think this latter info was essential to include in your question?

Comment: @RespawnedFluff Not necessary, i just want to know, if  it possible to do so. I have only basic knowledge  in electronics.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff  I searched for dedicated charger ICs, none of them are available in retail.